# Incorrect dropdown positioning of Autocomplete component for React Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

At expanding the Material-UI Autocomplete component the dropdown opens as expected. However once it is opened and I scroll it moves instead of staying positioned below the autocomplete box. I found that this behaviour should be fixed for the version of material ui that I use [as stated here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/4393). I also tested that for a plain new project on sandbox, where it worked fine.    
**Therefore, I expect to have unwillingly overwritten some important styling settings but could not figure out the mistake. Any ideas where I could look?** 
Following the relevant code snippet:

```
The component where I render the Autocomplete component
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
...,
  vinBox: {
    width: 320,
    marginTop: "4px"
  }
}));
...
return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="vin-selection"
      options={allVehicleVins}
      className={classes.vinBox}
      onChange={(event, data) => setFilter({ ...filter, vin: data })}
      value={filter.vin}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          margin={"normal"}
          label="VIN"
          variant="standard"
          InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="start">
                <DirectionsCar />
              </InputAdornment>
            )
          }}
          helperText={
            "Choose a VIN to filter for specific vehicles of your fleet."
          }
          fullWidth
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

I used Chrome Version 80.0.3987.149 (althoug also happened in other Browsers). Some of my dependencies:

```
...
"@material-ui/core": "^4.8.2",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.35",
"react": "^16.12.0",
...
```

[image: example of badly positioned dropdown]

Comment: btw my mainTheme in the App.js component is not overwriting any styles for this autocomplete component.

Comment: There is a prop named **PopperComponent** in the [document](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) which may help you fix the position of options

Comment: Please submit a codesanbox reproductible example.

Comment: @keikai thanks for letting me know! I set the `PopperComponent = {"bottom-start"}` of the Autocomplete. That worked for keeping the options at their place when scrolling. However, the options are now not overlapping the other elements but squeeze in and have the width of the container..
How can I pass in more options for the PopperComponent or adopt the stylin accordingly? I don't quite understand the documentation on that.

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI that is kind of the problem. I don't know at what point of my projects code it manipulates the behavior of the autocomplete component and therefore I am not able to reproduce it elsewhere. I'll try to do that asap. thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Sadly we can't help; I have the autocomplete in various places in my projects, and we never experienced this issue

Comment: by trying to reproduce it in sandbox I found my error. So thanks for helping without really being able to help :) have a nice day @MohamedELAYADI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after extensive testing I found my error. I have an `index.css` right in the `src` folder. In there I have following styling:

```
body {
  ...
  overflow-y: scroll;
  ...
}
```

changing this does the trick. Hope that helps anyone reading this :)

Answer (score 4):

sooo..

i found this error, and can't find the right answer.

so, my solution:

```
const Pop = props => {
  const { className, anchorEl, style, ...rest } = props
  const bound = anchorEl.getBoundingClientRect()
  return <div {...rest} style={{
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 9999,
    width: bound.width
  }} />
}
```

and

```
<Autocomplete
   ...
   PopperComponent={Pop}
   ...
/>
```